# Recursively manipulating strings

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring, indexof

The program this method belongs to encodes and decodes messages with a simple cipher (i.e 'ABCD' to '1,2,3,4' or '1,2,3,4' to 'ABCD'). The numbers the encoded message consists of are colon delimited. Each value in the string is supposed to be converted to ints, then to chars and finally concatenated into a result string. This method is supposed to recursively decode messages, but this is my first time messing with recursion so it is not yet functional. This is the error I have been receiving

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1".

The Method:

```
public static String DecodeR(String msg, String result) {
    if (msg.length()>0) {
       int pos =1;
       pos += msg.indexOf(",");
       int x = Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(0,msg.indexOf(",")));
       if (x==0) {
          x=32;
          return DecodeR ((msg.substring(msg.indexOf(pos))),result+=String.valueOf((char)x));
      } else if (x==99) {
          x=63;
          return DecodeR ((msg.substring(msg.indexOf(pos))),result+=String.valueOf((char)x));
      } else {
          x=x+64;
          return DecodeR ((msg.substring(msg.indexOf(pos))),result+=String.valueOf((char)x));
      }

    } else {
        return result;
    }
}//end of DecodeR
```

EDIT: I failed to properly set up the base case which caused the recursion to continue until it resulted in a negative index position. Also my understanding of substring and indexOf was lacking, resulting in incorrect string parsing in the first place. Finished code:

```
    public static String DecodeR(String msg, String result) {
    if (msg.length() == 0) {
       return result;
    }

    int commaPosition = msg.contains(",") ? msg.indexOf(",") : msg.length();
    int charCode = Integer.parseInt(msg.substring(0, commaPosition));

    String remainingString = msg.contains(",") ? msg.substring(commaPosition+1, msg.length()) : "";

    if (charCode == 0) {
       charCode = 32; 
    } else if (charCode == 99) {
       charCode = 63;
    } else {
       charCode += 64;
   }

    result += String.valueOf((char)charCode);
    return DecodeR(remainingString, result);

}//end of DecodeR
```

Thanks for all the help, your advice was greatly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by recursivly decoding messages? I'm having difficulty figuring out what your code is intended to do.  Give us an input that will recurse several times, and the output at each stage of recursion or - if too many stages - what it looks like at several significant stages.

Comment: You are using `indexOf` in the wrong way. It expects a string or a character and will find the location of the character inside the string. You hand over some kind of position. This position value is used as character and causes `msg.indexOf` to return `-1` because the character is not found inside the string.

Comment: If you can use Java 8, use collections and the map/filter methods, with lambdas.

Comment: some method is trying to get value of a string element that does not exist

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to decode this:

Say for example a = 1 and z = 26 and all the letters inbetween are their respective numbers, all you have to do is find every say 24 and replace it with x. This can be done by using the strings replace method, not you must replace in order of largest number to smallest number.

Eg.
`String decoded = encoded.replace("26", "z").replace("25", "y")........replace("1", "a").replace(",", "");`

This will allow you to assign numbers to each character and also remove the colons without the huge method you used before to replace them.